# How to define error types in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums

Suppose I define errors for my Scala application. I want them to be `Error`, `Warning`, and `Ok`. I would like the  `Error` and `Warning` to contain a human-readable text message.

I would like also to assign numerical codes (0 - for `Ok`, 1 - for `Warning`, and 2 - for `Error`) to find the most serious error in an errors list for example.

So, I define this error stuff as follows:

```
object MyErrors {  
  abstract sealed case class MyError(code: Int, maybeMessage: Option[String])
  object Ok extends MyError(0, None)
  final case class Warning(message) extends MyError(1, Some(message)) 
  final case class Error(message) extends MyError(2, Some(message))
}
```

Does it make sense? How would you implement it?

Comment: Is `(2 * Warning == Error)` ? :) If not, the concept of arithmetic data types is a bit overspecific. Maybe a rough grouping like in logging (severe, critical, fatal, ...) is better, and can just be modeled by inheritance. Also: The class `Either` might be useful for you.

Comment: Afterwards, it might be useful if he has more error values... For example, to filter every errors with a code greater than `x`.

Comment: Look at how Scala's Parsers Combinators encode results, which have a similar hierarchy.

Comment: @Nicolas It would be better to drop the numeric code and rather use Ordering/Ordered.

Comment: @paradigmatic I fully agree. I just have to figure out how to add `Ordering`.

Answer (score 8):

Several issues according to me:

1. You cannot extend a case class. Consider `sealed trait` or a simple `abstract class`
2. Why are all of them enclosed in the `MyErrors` object?
3. Do you really require the `Int` field? You can use pattern matching for filtering.
4. Having `Ok` as an instance of `MyError` looks semantically wrong. I would rather used `Status`
5. Matter of choice, but I Would have defined a subtrait for `ErroneousStatus`
6. Have you consider [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either) or [`Validation`](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/doc/scalaz/Validation.html) as an alternative before you came with your design ?

Comment: Re: 5, that way it won't remain an algebraic type any more.

Comment: @missingfaktor Not necessary:  `sealed trait Status` - `sealed traits ErroneousStatus extends Status` - and then the `object`/`case class`es...

Comment: @ Nicolas: While your criticisms are valid, this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @Nicolas, yes, that is not an ADT.

Answer (score 2):

This does what I think you're trying to do:

```
object MyErrors extends Enumeration {
  val Ok = Value("ok", 0)
  val Warning = Value("warning", 1)
  val Error = Value("error", 2)

  class TypeVal(val name: String, val code: Int) extends Val(nextId, name)

  protected final def Value(name: String, code: Int) = new TypeVal(name, code)

  sealed case class MyError(error: TypeVal, maybeMessage: Option[String])

  def ok(msg: Option[String] = None) = new MyError(Ok, msg)
  def error(msg: Option[String] = None) = new MyError(Error, msg)
  def warning(msg: Option[String] = None) = new MyError(Warning, msg)

}
```

Use as:

```
val e = MyErrors.error() 
// or
val f = MyErrors.ok(Option("Don't worry, be happy"))
f.error.code // Int = 0
f.maybeMessage // Option[String] = Some(Don't worry, be happy)
```

Obviously, it could be cleaned up quite a bit. But it should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Evolving on the suggestion about renaming your type to `Status` by Nicolas, here's some code with other niceties:

```
sealed trait Status {
  def code: Int
}
object Status {
  case object Ok extends Status {
    val code = 0
  }
  sealed trait WithMessage extends Status {
    def message: String
  }
  case class Warning (message: String) extends WithMessage {
    val code = 1
  }
  case class Error (message: String) extends WithMessage {
    val code = 2
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
scala> Status.Ok
res0: Status.Ok.type = Ok

scala> Status.Warning("blabla")
res1: Status.Warning = Warning(blabla)

scala> Status.Error("blabla").code
res2: Int = 2
```